# Returning immediate value and then call asyncio.sleep

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, timeout, python-asyncio

I need help with this exercise please, I have this function:

```
async def check_name(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        if SOmeFunction():
            DoSomethng
        else:
            DosomethingElse
```

Now I want to call the above function in other function but the prblem is that I want the below function to return an immediate value and then call check_name(). This is what I've done so far ( I thought of adding try.. finally but it didnt't work it is calling check_name first then waits 5 seconds and then it is returning the actual value. I want to return the value first then call check_name()

```
async def func():
        value = func2()
        try:
          return value

        finally:
          await self.check_name()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `asyncio.create_task` to instruct the event loop to await `check_name` itself, i.e. to run it in the background:

```
async def func():
    asyncio.create_task(self.check_name())
    value = func2()
```

Note that, if you do this, the return value of `check_name()` will not be available, and if it raises an exception, it will just be reported by the event loop.

Comment: Wow it worked I just added loop = asyncio.get_event_loop() before it, thanks man

Comment: @Hahahahah You shouldn't need the assignment to `loop` because the code doesn't use the variable, but it's still good to hear it worked for you. :)